# Avoid object allocations during draw/layout operations (preallocate and reuse instead) . how to avoid this warning.

Tags: android

i am trying to make a small rectangle in the middle of canvas but i am not getting any rectangle instead eclipse is showing a warning `"Avoid object allocations during draw/layout operations (preallocate and reuse instead)"`what kind of warning is this and what could be the reason for the absence of rectangle.

```
Rect middleRect=new Rect();
middleRect.set(0,400,canvas.getWidth(),550);
Paint ourBlue = new Paint();
ourBlue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
canvas.drawRect(middleRect,ourBlue);
invalidate();
```

Comment: try middleRect.set
(0,0,100,100) and see if its shown

Comment: so now you know what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

For warning, eclipse is notifying you to improve the object initializing in onDraw() method as

```
Rect middleRect=new Rect();
Paint ourBlue = new Paint();
```

Better way could be to declare these object at class level and initialize them in constructor, and just make drawXxx() calls in onDraw method.